# Object creation using inheritance in require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the following two files:

**product.js** ,

```
 define(function(products) {
  return {
    reserveProduct: function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    }
  }
});
```

**purchase.js**

```
define(["products"], function(products) {
  return {
    function(id) {
     products.reserveProduct(id);
    }
  }
})
```

I am creating a purchase object.

```
new purchase(1);
```

Now I want to extend  purchase.js as `AnalyExtendpurchase.js` and create a new object as

```
new AnalyExtendpurchase(1);
```

I  want to pass id as parameter to parent object i.e to purchase object

Normally in Java the equivalent code would be:

**Purchase.java**

```
public class Purchase{
  purchase(int id){
    this.id=id;
  }
}
```

**AnalyExtendpurchase.java**

```
 AnalyExtendpurchase extends purchase{
   AnalyExtendpurchase(int id){
     super(id);
   }
 }
```

Object creation in java

```
new AnalyExtendpurchase(10);
```

I want to follow same object creation pattern using requirejs.

Comment: Why are you calling `purchase` with `new`? It doesn't look anything like a constructor, it doesn't intialise any instance.

Comment: Forget about require.js at first and learn how to use JavaScript in a single file. (Putting everything in its own module is trivial afterwards). I recommend to have a look at the ES6 `class` syntax.

Comment: I have restriction to use require.js and i have restriction to follow inheritance pattern .

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a sample example below : Hope it can help you ..

Let's say we have ABC() constructor like:

```
function ABC(firstName, lastName){
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;

}
```

Then Let's define XYZ() constructor function,

```
function XYZ(firstName, lastName,subject) {
  ABC.call(this, firstName, lastName);

  this.subject = subject;
}
```

Here call() is used to call a function defined somewhere else, but in the current context

Finally you can set XYZ() prototype as :

```
XYZ.prototype = Object.create(ABC.prototype);
XYZ.prototype.constructor = XYZ;
```

Here, above line create a new object and make it the value of XYZ.prototype and will inherit from ABC.prototype

Hope the above prototypal inheritance sample helps you . happy coding :)